# Validar que el registro no exista en una base de datos

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio

Tengo un programa sencillo y quiero validar que exista algún dato antes de insertarlo, es decir que arroje un mensaje diciéndome que ese registro existe.

El problema es que me inserta datos y el mismo existe.

Debugeando me di cuenta que en el segundo **if** debe traerme en la variable **con** lo mismo que **codigo**

pero me trae la consulta completa es decir "SELECT * FROM ....."

ANEXO CODIGO

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string codigo = txtCode.Text;
            string nombre = txtName.Text;
            string descripcion = txtDescription.Text;
            double precio = double.Parse(txtPrice.Text);
            int existencia = int.Parse(txtExistence.Text);

            if (codigo != "" && nombre != "" && descripcion != "" && precio > 0 && existencia > 0)
            {
                string con = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTO WHERE codigo = '" + codigo + "'";
                string sql = "INSERT INTO PRODUCTO (codigo, nombre, descripcion, precio, existencia)" +
                             " VALUES ('" + codigo + "','" + nombre + "','" + descripcion + "','" + precio + "','" + existencia + "')";
                
                SqlConnection conexionBD = Conexiona.conexion();
                conexionBD.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(con, conexionBD);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("codigo", codigo);
                if (con == codigo)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Registro Ya Existe");
                }
                else {
                    try
                    {
                        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(sql, conexionBD);
                        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        MessageBox.Show("Datos Guardado");
                    }
                    catch (SqlException ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("No Pudo Guardar Los Datos Debido A: " + ex.Message);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        conexionBD.Close();
                    }
                }
                clean();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("LLenar Cada Campo");
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException fex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Datos Erroneo : " + fex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

//Reemplazar...

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("codigo", codigo);
 if (con == codigo)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Registro Ya Existe");
    }
```

//Por...

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("codigo", codigo);
using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Registro Ya Existe");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias user12184828, funciono perfecto

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).